# Add div after every 3d element twig loop, modulus

Tags: loops, twig, modulus

Hi so i have this twig loop, and what i need to to is after every 3rd element to add some html to close div row and open new one.

I tried with various snippets from this website but no luck with any one of them

```
<div class="row">
    {% for date, date_info in dates %}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="event-box">
                {% for category in date_info.events %}
                    {% for event in category %}
                        <div class="event-header">
                            {% if event.get_runtime( 'content_img_url' ) is empty %}
                                {{ event | avatar( [
                                'post_thumbnail',
                                'location_avatar',
                                'category_avatar'
                                ]) | raw }}
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="event-date">
                                {{ date | month }}
                                {{ date | day }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-footer">
                                <h3>{{ event.get_runtime( 'filtered_title' ) | raw }}</h3>
                                <div class="event-time">
                                    {{ event | timespan( 'short' ) | raw }}...
                                </div>
                                <div class="event-content"> {{ event.get_runtime( 'filtered_content' ) | slice(0,200) | raw }}</div>

                                <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ event.get_runtime( 'instance_permalink' ) | e('html_attr') }}">
                                    {{ text_read_more }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %} {# event in category #}
                {% endfor %} {# category in date_info.events #}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %} {# date, date_info in dates #}
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt here. Did you try the `batch` filter?

Comment: Your question is too long for the matter you are asking. Please, consider shortening it. Full HTML snippet seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html) filter instead (New in 1.12.3).

```
{% for date, date_info in dates|batch(3) %}
   .....
   .....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yup! This is amazing and works great. Far more helpful.

Comment: This is a great solution.

Answer (score 20):

I think this is better solution:

```
{% for date, date_info in dates %}
   {% if loop.first %}
      <div class="row"> {# open row #}
   {% endif %}


       {# your code here #}


    {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
        </div><div class="row"> {# after 3 iterates close row and open new #}
    {% endif %}                
    {% if loop.last %}
        </div> {# close last row #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This answer might be good, but could you add an explanation as to what it's doing and why it might solve the OPs problem?

Comment: The code is self-explanatory, this is a better answer.

Answer (score 16):

Got it working with {% if loop.index is divisible by(3) and not loop.last %}.

Here is my full working code example :

```
<div class="row">

    {% for date, date_info in dates %}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="event-box">
                {% for category in date_info.events %}
                    {% for event in category %}
                        <div class="event-header">
                            {% if event.get_runtime( 'content_img_url' ) is empty %}
                                {{ event | avatar( [
                                'post_thumbnail',
                                'location_avatar',
                                'category_avatar'
                                ]) | raw }}
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="event-date">
                                {{ date | month }}
                                {{ date | day }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-footer">
                                <h3>{{ event.get_runtime( 'filtered_title' ) | raw }}</h3>

                                <div class="event-time">
                                    {{ event | timespan( 'short' ) | raw }}...
                                </div>
                                <div class="event-content"> {{ event.get_runtime( 'filtered_content' ) | slice(0,200) | raw }}</div>

                                <a class="btn btn-success"
                                   href="{{ event.get_runtime( 'instance_permalink' ) | e('html_attr') }}">
                                    {{ text_read_more }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %} {# event in category #}
                {% endfor %} {# category in date_info.events #}
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if loop.index is divisibleby(3) and not loop.last %}
        </div>

        <div class="row">

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %} {# date, date_info in dates #}

</div>
```

Comment: I think this is not totally correct. If you have 3 items this will let the "<div class="row">" open. You should close the div outside of the loop and add "and not loop.last" in the "if condition" to prevent this.

Answer (score 7):

In reading this doc : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

I'll try this kind of code :

```
{% for date, date_info in dates %}
   {% if  loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
       {# put your code to close your div #}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @benedict_w Thanks ^^